# Grid - paging toolbar

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm  working on ExtJS grid(extjs4.2). I have used [Paging Toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) for the grid.

I have also written a search code using grid filter and i'm performing store reload to display the searched results, the grid is getting updated. But the paging toolbar is not getting updated(the totalCount is not getting updated).

this is my search code

```
{
xtype : 'button',
margin : '1 10 1 33',
text : 'Search',
handler : function() {
    var search_text = Ext.getCmp('searchText').getValue();
    agent_store.clearFilter(true);
    agent_store.filter('descriptiveName', search_text);
    Ext.getCmp('grid_agents').getStore().reload();
    agent_store.load({start:0,limit:15});  
    agent_store.loadPage(1);
    searchWindow.close();
}
}
```

Can anyone help me???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us your Model definition and the returned Json from the server.

Comment: Most likely you don't apply the filter to the DB request that collects the total count...

Comment: I'm working with static data, i dont get data from DB. Its a userdefined static json

Comment: If it's local data, you'll have to load the entire data set and use the http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy

Comment: Can yu give an example code for grid with pagingmemory proxy...i cant find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot the params keyword

```
store.load({
  params: {
    start: 0,
    limit: 15
 }...
```